# Relative parent with overflow: hidden, fixed child does not obey

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I am trying to create a `relative`-positioned element with `overflow:hidden` that contains a few `fixed`-position elements. The goal is to have the `fixed` child elements become hidden as the parent element moves, sort of like if they were part of a `background-image` with `attachment:fixed` on the parent element.

By all accounts on StackOverflow and elsewhere on the web, this is not possible, because a fixed element only regards the browser window and ignores its parent element. However, for whatever reason it actually works as intended in Chrome  only: http://jsfiddle.net/x6avvhuf/

Here's what the fiddle looks like, view it in Chrome vs. IE/Firefox to see the difference:

HTML

```
<body>
<div id = "headwrapper">
    I am the relative parent element
    <div class = "fixedchild">
        I am a fixed child element
    </div>
</div>
<div id = "content">
    This is the main content portion of the page<br>
    <!-- Repeat until the page scrolls -->
    This is the main content portion of the page<br>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
   background-color: yellow;
}

#headwrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.fixedchild {
    position: fixed;
    width: 75%;
    height: 40px;
    z-index: 48;
    top: 22.5%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 0 0 -37.5%;
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
    background-color: pink;
}
```

What is an alternative solution for this? I have read that it is possible to make an `absolute` element behave like a `fixed` element with CSS, but I have been unable to make this work so far. Thanks in advance for any help or advice! :)

Comment: I'm looking your fiddle. With Chrome or Firefox i got the same wrong result. Are you sure that it works in Chrome?

Comment: Yes, and it's working on the actual site I'm building. Only in Chrome, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Sometimes the best solutions are the most simple. Given the code you posted all you would have to do is set a `background-color` on `#content` (ex: `yellow` in this instance to match the `body`) since your fixed element has `z-index: -1` and will sit behind it anyways:

```
#content{
   background: yellow;
   width: 100%;
}
```

[**CSS EXAMPLE 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/x6avvhuf/4/)

## **OR**

You could set `#content` to `position:relative` which would allow you to order this and your fixed div with `z-index` (this is probably better, using `z-index: -1` is kind of a hack):

**CSS**

```
.fixedchild {
   position: fixed;  
   width: 75%;
   height: 40px;
   z-index: 1; //set to 1
   top: 22.5%;
   left: 50%;
   margin: 0 0 0 -37.5%;
   text-align: center;
   color: red;
   background-color: pink;
}

#content{
   background: yellow;
   width: 100%;
   position: relative; //add
   z-index: 2; //set higher
}
```

[**CSS EXAMPLE 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/x6avvhuf/6/)

(**previous answer**):

**DISCLAMIER**: This is not a CSS solution.

There may be a CSS solution for this. I don't happen to know one off the top of my head, but I do know this can be done pretty easily with Jquery

**JS**

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   var scrolled = $(this).scrollTop()+100; //offset starting position which I hard coded to top: 100px - you can change as needed
   $(".fixedchild").css({"top": scrolled+"px"});  
});
```

**CSS**

```
.fixedchild {
   position: absolute;
   width: 75%;
   height: 40px;
   z-index: 48;
   top: 100px;
   left: 50%;
   margin: 0 0 0 -37.5%;
   text-align: center;
   color: red;
   background-color: pink;
}
```

[**JS EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/x6avvhuf/3/)

Comment: Thank you, if I can't find a CSS solution I'll refer to this :)

Comment: I just tried doing some googling real quick and didnt find anything. I havent heard of that and I would say im pretty confident that this is not possible with CSS but you learn new things everyday

Comment: @fishang I spoke to soon, figured out a different solution. Updated my answer

Comment: I see, the updated solution does indeed work for the code provided. The site I'm building is a bit more complex—one of the 'fixed' child elements is an HTML5 video and the `#content` area, done this way, would require a `background-image` with `attachment: fixed`. The reason I have the background applied to `body` is a Chrome-specific bug in which a video element causes fixed-attachment background images to render erratically on scrolling elements. I spent a day trying to solve that one already, unfortunately :( apologies for not including that information, I didn't think it would come up.

Comment: @fishang ah i see. Could you recreate this by any chance? or post a link to your site?

Comment: I tried to recreate it in jsfiddle, but I couldn't seem to do it, so here's the site: http://andrewfishel.com/current/craig/build/ I set the background-color on `#page-wrapper` to pink so that you can see the erratic loading of the background image in Chrome

Comment: Thanks, so where is the actual issue?

Comment: View the page in Chrome and scroll down. On my end, the background-image only loads in random chunks when I activate the `:hover` states on other elements. On other browsers it works as intended, but as long as `background-attachment` is set to `fixed` on `#pagewrapper`, the whole background falls apart.

Comment: I suppose the issue as it relates to my original question is that when the `background-image` and associated properties are set to `body`, the `fixed` elements within `#headwrapper` don't disappear when they become overflow of `#headwrapper` as it scrolls up the page.

Comment: @fishang I updated my answer, try what I posted at the bottom

Comment: Still getting blocky, erratic loading :( Like I said, I spent a whole day looking for a fix to this bug to no avail, so I had hoped I could find an alternate CSS solution. It seems to be more trouble than it's worth though, so I'll just use your jQuery solution instead, and maybe I'll split this issue off into a new question. Thanks for your help! :)